# How to add custom command in Xtermjs

Tags: javascript, xtermjs

I want to create a custom terminal with my own commands and responses with [Xterm.js](https://xtermjs.org/) (in browser).

How do I create a command like this below:

```
# input:
>getInfo

# do the logic I wrote in a script

# output:
>Information about something
```

Comment: xterm.js' primary goal is to run behind a PTY. There you'd write your command with whatever your shell | cmdline interpreter can work with (a shell script, a binary etc). If you want to run JS from within the browser things are much more involved - you'd need to write your own shell + some PTY abstraction first, before you have a working env which can call "commands". Maybe https://github.com/wavesoft/local-echo can help you with that.

Comment: @jech thanks for helping. now I have a new idea. I just want to use simple html inputs.